# Find each div by class name in a div based on a DOM objects location

Tags: jquery

I need to find all the divs in a div with the class name `.types_list_button`. The parent div is `.types_list`. I have several `.types_list` on the page so I have the location of the div into an object like `thisforsure_object.parent()`

I have a DOM object for my current location but my code does not seem to traverse up to the parent then back to find `.each()` div `.types_list_button`

If my code worked correctly it should alert me 5 times

**HTML**

```
<div class="types_list"> <--- parent()
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
    <div class="types_list_button"></div> <--- this is thisforsure_object.parent()
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(thisforsure_object.parent()).parent().each('.types_list_button', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: 1) You're creating a jQuery object from the result of the first `parent()` call, which is already a jQuery object. You don't need to do that 2) `each()` doesn't take a selector as its first argument. I presume you want `find()` first, ie. `.parent().find('.types_list_button').each(...`. I'd also suggest reading the docs: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#thisIsObject').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.types_list').find('.types_list_button')   .each(function() {
    alert('test');
  });
});
```

You should go back to `parent(types_list)` then inside that can find `types_list_button` so can `alert` 5 times.
I've added an example with button, onclick will `alert` 5 times.
this is an example:

```js
$('#thisIsObject').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.types_list').find('.types_list_button')   .each(function() {
    alert('test');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="types_list">
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
      <button id="thisIsObject">
        this is thisforsure_object.parent()
      </button>
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
    <div class="types_list_button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it but had to make a small change, I edited your script

Comment: @CesarBielich (Y)